# Why does for loop not work in setText Method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a repeating text app. So I use a `for` loop for repeating the text and display this text in a `textview`.

When I press a button then I want it to generate the text as many times as the loop runs.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    enterText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    repeatText = findViewById(R.id.repeatTime);

    genTxt = findViewById(R.id.genText);

    genrate = findViewById(R.id.generate);
    reset = findViewById(R.id.reset);

    copy = findViewById(R.id.copyButton);
    share = findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

    genrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Storing text in Gen Text Area
            String txt = enterText.getText().toString().trim();

            //Storing Repeat value
            String repeats = repeatText.getText().toString().trim();
            int repealVal = Integer.parseInt(repeats);

            for(int i=1;i<=repealVal;i++){
                genTxt.setText(txt);
                Log.d("tets","loop "+i+txt);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void reset(View view){
    enterText.setText("");
    repeatText.setText("");
    genTxt.setText("");
}
```

When I run it I only get the text one time in my `textview`.

Comment: You are simply replacing the txt each time with the same txt `genTxt.setText(txt);`

Comment: The Text object is being overriden everytime you call setText(). Elaborating: You need to either concatenate the input or generate a new object each time. I suggest the first suggestion

Comment: use `append` instead of `setText`

Comment: if you got correct answer to your question, please that answer as correct

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your `onClick` method to the following:

```
genrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //Storing text in Gen Text Area
    String txt = enterText.getText().toString().trim();

    //Storing Repeat value
    String repeats = repeatText.getText().toString().trim();
    int repealVal = Integer.parseInt(repeats);

    for(int i=1;i<=repealVal;i++){
      genTxt.setText(genTxt.getText() + txt);
      Log.d("tets","loop "+i+txt);
    }
  }
});
```

Note that inside the loop you are only switching the text, not adding to the text.

To even further optimize solution, you should consider using .`append()` instead of `.setText()`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting text to same `TextView` again and again.
If you want to dynamically generate multiple `TextView`s you can try below solution.

Give an id to your root layout in `xml` where you want to add text. Here I am using `LinearLayout`. Add it in your code as below:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll) //ll is the id of LinearLayout
```

Then add this in your `onclick`

```
TextView txtView;  
for(int i = 1; i <= repealVal; i++) {
    txtView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    txtView.setText(txt);
    linearLayout.addView(txtView);
}
```

Comment: I think that appending string to one multi-line TextView would be more optimized solution than creating numerous TextViews.